# Good TN3270 for MacOS? (Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, emulation

I need a good TN3270 emulator for the Mac that supports file transfers to TSO/ISPF (IND$FILE) and 132 char wide screens.  Min 132x27 (3278-model-5), better even user defined size like 132x43.

So far I've tried TN3270 (no file transfer) and X3270.  Besides being an X11 app, unfortunately x3270 does not handle oversize screens correctly and Mocha only has a TN5250.

So, what's the TN3270 of choice on the Mac (or how at least do I get x3270 to handle 132xSomething in ISPF correctly, e.g. SDSF Job-Class list)?

Comment: curious; why do you need TN3270? last mainframe I used was shut down just past Y2K, though I saw Niketown with 3270 terminal emulation more recently than that.

Answer (score 2):

There's possibly [Jagacy](http://www.topshareware.com/Jagacy-download-36461.htm), the  [TN3270 emulator from Brown University](http://mac.wareseeker.com/Utilities/brown-university-tn3270-3.1.1.zip/328770).  The ZOC terminal emulator which I'm using also lists [TN3270 and IND$FILE as features](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/features.html).  I have not used these though, so I don't know if they meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Or [TN3270](http://www.brown.edu/cis/tn3270/).  This does not appear to be Jagacy, Jagacy appears to be a windows package?  At least according to the link it is...

Comment: Say's it's not Intel native, will this run under snow leopard? I know a lot of Classic and emulator stuff was pulled.

Comment: TN3270 is an Universal Application... tn3270 X 3.3b6 (universal binary, beta) is available.  We use it at work without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The [Open Mainframe Project](https://www.openmainframeproject.org/) may have a solution here. [Zowe](https://zowe.github.io/docs-site/latest/user-guide/mvd-using.html#iframe-sample) lists Mac as a [supported platform](https://zowe.github.io/docs-site/user-guide/systemrequirements.html#prerequisite-software).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is: x3270 should work just fine. It has an '-oversize' option to set the screen to any size that fits within the 3270 protocol.